# Is there a way to check if a certain mail is sent in gmail with apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I want to get a certain mail with a certain subject from the gmail sent folder, how can I achieve this? just guide me where to look or put snippets of code that might be helpful, just basic if condition comparing retrieved sent mail subject to a subject_variable.

algorithm for my logic:

```
var subject_variable = "specific subject"

[some code to retrieve specific sent mail with subject_variable]

if(retrieved sent mail subject == subject_variable) 
return 0; 

else execute other part of code I prepared already
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use [GmailApp.search](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery)

Here you can specify parameters like subject or label.

Sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  var messages = GmailApp.search("in : sent subject : specific subject");
  Logger.log("There are " + messages.length + " messages in Sent matching with the specified query.");
}
```

Comment: will it work if I made it like this?

var messages = GmailApp.search("in : sent subject :  + subject_variable +");

Comment: Almost: `var messages = GmailApp.search("in : sent subject : " + subject_variable + ' " ');`

Comment: thank you for your help, man:)
I will try it out and if it achieves the purpose of my question I will mark your answer as a solution, if not, I will come with feedback. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you man for posting your answer. It worked but needed simple modifications to make it work, as there were unnecessary spaces that made the compiler read the subject improperly. here's it after fixing it:

var messages = GmailApp.search("in:sent subject:" + Subject);

all thanks go to you man:) I was able to achieve my purpose successfully.